# Response on same page using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, load

I have been designing a simple backup manager script. Its main function is to send backup file to another destination with just a click using ftp.

I have been using following link to send backup details to **ftp.php** file:

```
<a href=\"ftp.php?name=$name&file=$location\"><img src=\"./move.png\"></a>
```

And the FTP.php file is:

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET['name'];
$file = $_GET['file'];

/* Remote File Name and Path */
$remote_file = "/$name";

/* File and path to send to remote FTP server */
$local_file = './$file';

/* FTP Account (Remote Server) */
$ftp_host = 'ftp.domain.com'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'pass'; /* password */


/* File and path to send to remote FTP server */

/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login to FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Send $local_file to FTP */
if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    echo "WOOT! Successfully transfer $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );

?>
```

So I want to run this entire script on single page and get ftp response "WOOT! Successfully transfer $local_file\n" or fail on main page itself..

Any one?

Comment: Deleted that tag..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.